# Añadir evento de click en botón por Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy en medio de un proyecto web en el cual un botón esta oculto y lo muestro cuando accedo a una página. Para esto, hago uso de `jquery`.

El problema resulta que a la hora de añadir el evento al botón oculto, el evento se activa. Resumiendo, el evento se une al botón pero también se ejecuta una vez.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Probé con lo siguiente:

```
$("#cuadro_opciones").toggle()
$("#concretar_oferta").on("click",myFuncion())
```

En mi código, e incluso probando en la consola del navegador y aún así pasa.

Comment: quieres que el evento se ejecute en un boton oculto? o quieres que funcione al hacerlo aparecer?

Comment: Deberías poner el código completo... puede que la función se llame desde otra parte o que hayan otros elementos con el mismo id... Si no muestras todo el código será difícil determinar lo que ocurre.

Comment: usas eventPreventDefault?

Comment: Quiero que el botón aparezca y después asignarle la función, pero que solo se ejecute cuando se de click.

Comment: SaitoHs: en lugar de marcar como "solucionado", publica tu propia respuesta y acéptala → [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 5):

Imagino que esto es lo que te está pasando:

```js
$("#concretar_oferta").on("click",myFuncion())

function myFuncion(){
  console.log('hola');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="concretar_oferta">Ejecutar</button>
```

Te explico, al momento de asignar la función al evento estás usando los paréntesis () con lo cual estás ejecutando la función inmediatamente, entonces para solucionar esto solo debes asignar la función únicamente por su nombre, sin paréntesis:

```js
$("#concretar_oferta").on("click",myFuncion)

function myFuncion(){
  console.log('hola');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="concretar_oferta">Ejecutar</button>
```

Comment: Pero, ¿Qué pasa si necesito pasar parámetros?

Comment: @SaitoHs hermano la verdad no sabría como, una opción es escribir la función ahí mismo en el evento y no aparte

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquerys-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function

Comment: Solucionado! Tuve que hacer cambios y poner myFunction() a function(){myFunction()}) y funciona bien!

Comment: @SaitoHs mira el enlace que comparte azeós, muy bueno, acabo de aprender algo nuevo.

Comment: Gracias @azeós por tu colaboración